# Spring framework: No message found under code for locale

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, message

This is my messageResource declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Auto-detect controllers in this package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="levelup.world.web" />

    <!-- Prepend /WEB-INF/jsp/ and append .jsp to the view name -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Access resource bundles with the specified basename -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basename="/WEB-INF/messages/" />

</beans>
```

When I run my application, this error shows up

```
No message found under code 'country.plural' for locale 'fil_PH'
```

now inside my messages folder inside web-inf, I have the following message properties

```
messages_en.properties
messages_fr.properties
messages.properties
```

What Am I missing here?

Comment: First all your messages here? fil_PH may be another properties file for your message folder.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In general such issue appears not because of non-existence locale, but because `MessageBundle` is configured improperly. In your case you seem to need to remove "/" in your basename.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
     class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
     p:basename="/WEB-INF/messages" />
```

Why it is so:

If you have `messages.properties` and `messages_en.properties` bundle, then bundle name is `messages`. If you have them in the `WEB-INF` folder, then basename is `/WEB-INF/messages`, i.e. according to /`path/to/bundle/bundlename`. If you have `messages.properties` within `/WEB-INF/messages` folder, then corresponding basename is `/WEB-INF/messages/messages`.

Comment: why do I need to remove the '/' ?

Comment: You need to remove "/" because when you specify basename, you should use such structure: `/path/to/bundle/bundlename`. And could you please tell whether it helped?

Comment: I thought it was the folder I was referring or the folder that contains the message resources, am I wrong?

Comment: Let's see: if you have `messages.properties` and `messages_en.properties` bundle, then bundle name is `messages`. If you have them in the `WEB-INF` folder, then basename is `/WEB-INF/messages`, i.e. according to `/path/to/bundle/bundlename`. If you have `messages.properties` within `/WEB-INF/messages` folder, then corresponding basename is `/WEB-INF/messages/messages`

Comment: What's MessageBundle and where do I configure it?

Comment: @n1ckolas Hi I am trying to follow the answer above but it is not working still. I am getting the same error message, do you have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Adding to answer, if properties file is under any directory inside resource - e.g. resources/messages/exception-messages.properties then basename -"messages/exception-messages". Faced this issue myself, that's why putting it here!

Answer (score 14):

For spring boot you need something like this:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
     ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
     messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/classes/messages");
     return messageSource;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For spring boot folder ressources you need to add name of Bean:

```
@Bean(name="messageSource")
public ResourceBundleMessageSource bundleMessageSource() {
ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
messageSource.setBasename("messages");
return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: Adding to answer, if properties file is under any directory inside resource - e.g. resources/messages/exception-messages.properties then basename -"messages/exception-messages". Faced this issue myself, that's why putting it here!

Answer (score 4):

You can specify in Spring boot application.properties too

```
# INTERNATIONALIZATION 
spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add some code in application.properties:

```
spring.messages.always-use-message-format=false
spring.messages.basename=messages
spring.messages.cache-seconds=-1
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=true
```

Comment: why spring.messages.always-use-message-format=false

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help someone.

```
errors.rejectValue("fieldName", "errorCode", "textException");
```

If you don't using messageResource like I do then you should write "" instead of "errorCode".

Example:

```
errors.rejectValue("name", "", "This field should not be empty");
```

This way helped me to avoid the exception.

Answer (score -1):

By default maven assumes to find such resource bundle message source under

> src/main/resources

. By moving all the necessary folders under the location and also making sure we have the following code in the context

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename"><value>messages</value></property>
</bean>
```