# Spring mvc, RedirectAttributes not working

Tags: spring, validation, model-view-controller

I am trying RedirectAttributes in my webapp, But some how its not picking up my error message, here is my code and error messages.

its MyUtil class

```
     @Component
    public class MyUtil {

        @Autowired
        public MyUtil(MessageSource messageSource) {
              MyUtil.messageSource = messageSource;
        }

       public static void flash(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
       String kind, String messageKey) {

            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashKind", kind);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashMessage",
            MyUtil.getMessage(messageKey));

      }

        private static MessageSource messageSource;

      public static String getMessage(String messageKey, Object... args)      {
                return messageSource.getMessage(messageKey, args,        
                Locale.getDefault());
        }

    }
```

and here is my controller's post method

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String homePost(@ModelAttribute("signupForm") @Valid    
    SignupForm signupForm, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, 
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)  
    {

           if(result.hasErrors()) {


                MyUtil.flash(redirectAttributes, "success","registerError");


                 return "redirect:/";
          }

    subserv.subscriber(signupForm);
    model.addAttribute("name", signupForm.getName());
    return "subscribers";
```

its my message.properties

```
    registerError=e-mail already Registered.
```

and here is my error message

```
    org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'regsiterError' for locale 'en_IN'.
at org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource.getMessage(DelegatingMessageSource.java:69) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at com.example.util.MyUtil.getMessage(MyUtil.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.util.MyUtil.flash(MyUtil.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.controller.RootController.homePost(RootController.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the cause is just a typo `registerError` vs `regiterError`

**new stacktrace same problem**

again, you have the same problem:  `registerError` vs `regsiterError` (wrong order of `i` and `s`)

Comment: Yes I noticed it, But problem remains even when i corrected the typo

Comment: But not with this stacktrace! - we can just help you to fix something if the stacktrace is the one that is the cause for your problem.

Comment: this is what i have got after the correction of the typo

Comment: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'regsiterError' for locale 'en_IN'.
 at org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource.getMessage(DelegatingMessageSource.java:69) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at com.example.util.MyUtil.getMessage(MyUtil.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.example.util.MyUtil.flash(MyUtil.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.example.controller.RootController.homePost

Comment: I Have edited the error message in my question, now it is the error I am getting after correction of the typo

Comment: you have not fixed the typo correctly! (see my extend answer)

Comment: Phew... It is working now :-) error was silly , I made a typo in naming my messages.properties file, I named it as message.properties :-) and I was searching almost everything on regarding the error :-)

Comment: Typo was a right thing, but I was searching it in my code then the filename

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't configure your messageSource, can you provide how you configure your messageSource?

EDIT: you can check with [Spring framework: No message found under code for locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065734/spring-framework-no-message-found-under-code-for-locale)

Comment: do I need to configure it ? is'nt it auto configured ? My messages.properties file exists in resource folder, also I have annotated my application class with @EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: Phew... It is working now :-) error was silly , I made a typo in naming my messages.properties file, I named it as message.properties :-) and I was searching almost everything on regarding the error  :-)