# JVM Cache corruption due to spring frame work

Tags: spring

We had an issue with one of application while trying to lookup a property and the return value it is getting is NULL. Can any one help here, what could be an issue with the spring framework as my JVM support is claiming that this could be a known issue with Spring frame work.

Code snippet

```
@Autowired private MessageSource resource;

String[] propertieNames = resource.getMessage("signon.ceproperties.list.keys", null, null).split(",");
```

Exception Details

```
OMM 2018-06-28T06:00:00,612 DEBUG [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'  org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under
code 'signon.ceproperties.list.keys' for locale 'null'.
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:135)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether the basename i.e directory path is set for message source
like below

```
 @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
         ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
         messageSource.setBasename("<the directory path of your messages file>");
         return messageSource;
    }
```

Check this post [Spring framework: No message found under code for locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065734/spring-framework-no-message-found-under-code-for-locale) for more details