# NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have added the internalization functionnality to my app, however I'm still getting an exception

This is my config File that contains the messageSource configuration

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocaleConfiguration.class);

    /**
     * * @return default Locale set by the user
     */
    @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return slr;
    }

    /**
     * an interceptor bean that will switch to a new locale based on the value of the lang parameter appended to a request:
     *
     * @param registry
     * @language should be the name of the request param i.e  localhost:8010/api/get-all-exceptions/1?language=fr
     * <p>
     * Note: All requests to the backend needing Internalization should have the "language" request param
     */
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean("messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource ();
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(true);
        return resourceBundleMessageSource;
    }
```

And this is my service that uses the messageSource

```
@Service
public class LocaleServiceImpl implements LocaleService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocaleServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public String getMessage(ErrorDictionnary code, String... params) {
        return this.messageSource.getMessage(code.toString(), params, Locale.ENGLISH);
    }

}
```

When I try to Post ?language=en, I get this error :

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'ERROR_FIND_TRANSCODIFICATION' for locale 'en'.
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:161)
    at fr.cnp.aec.commons.services.impls.LocaleServiceImpl.getMessage(LocaleServiceImpl.java:38)
```

I get this error each time, I have checked and the propeties file are there _en and _fr

EDIT:

The code in the message.properties was wrong

Comment: You either have A) invalid configuration, or B) the variable "ERROR_FIND_TRANSCODIFICATION" is not found under your message_en file.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065734/spring-framework-no-message-found-under-code-for-locale/39371075

Comment: Thanks Susan, you're right, I had a missing N in the at the end of the code. I was pretty sure that my messages were ok.